When can $RHom^\bullet_{A}(B/I^k\overset{L}{\otimes}_B A, A)$ be computed using formal completions?
Let $\varphi:B\to A$ be a ring homomorphism between Noetherian rings. Let $I\subset B$ be an ideal. Let $B^{\wedge}=\varprojlim_n B/I^n$ be the $I$-adic completion of $B$, and $A^{\wedge}=\varprojlim_n A/(A\cdot\varphi(I))^n$ be the $A\cdot\varphi(I)$-adic completion of $A$. Let $I^\wedge=B^\wedge\cdot I$.
Question: Is it true that for every $k\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, the natural map induced by  $\overset{L}{\otimes}_A A^\wedge=\otimes_A A^\wedge$
$$RHom^\bullet_{A}(B/I^k\overset{L}{\otimes}_B A, A)\to RHom^\bullet_{A^\wedge}(B^\wedge/(I^\wedge)^k\overset{L}{\otimes}_{B^\wedge} A^\wedge, A^\wedge)$$
is an isomorphism? If not, under what conditions (not assuming $A$ is flat over $B$), the map is an isomorphism?
